# how to disable folders/files under root folder in RHEL?

Tags: linux, files, root

I want to "disable" listing of folders and files under root folder in RHEL. So when I login to my application nothing should be visible in root folder.

Comment: I would suggest looking at chroot/ssh jail as a better option = http://allanfeid.com/content/creating-chroot-jail-ssh-access / http://how-to.linuxcareer.com/how-to-automatically-chroot-jail-selected-ssh-user-logins

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to disable **your** application to see anything in the root directory, the easiest way is to change **your** application to check if the absolute rewrite of any path starts with `/` and take appropriate action.
You need to work with the absolute paths to prevent workarounds like `../../..` from some location down the tree.

That way you can even easily differentiate between different "users" logging into your application having different rights (some might see root, others don't). No need to disable anything, that easily might affect other program running on your system.